# Extract Order information and customer information from new order email

Tags: magento, magento-1.5, html-email, magento-1.6

I want to extract Order information and customer information from new order email which is sent to the customer after purchasing any product from Magento Website.

I have tried a lot but not getting any results as such.

Is this possible in Magento, I am stuck up in this problem since days.Does any one have a solution to this?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this data? Why must you get it from the new order email?

Comment: i need to POST this data to an external site for further processing. long with this data I need to POST the customer email also. Is this possible? Please let me know. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sending of new order emails is handled in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`.

Most Magento model classes (all which extend `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`) implement the [Template Method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) - not to be confused with view templates. The template methods can be used to hook in to save, load, and delete workflows in two ways:

1. Method rewrites via config-based class overrides (another Magento treat)
2. Observe events dispatched in the template methods.

By far the preferred technique for hooking into model execution is the event-observer system. Additionally, there are hundreds of events dispatched throughout Magento for any given execution.